# Why is the pseudo-random number generator less likely to generate 54 big numbers in a row?

Tags: c#, .net, random

Consider an event that occurs with probability *p*.  This program checks how many failed trials it takes before the event occurs and keeps a histogram of the totals.  e.g.:  If *p* were 0.5, then this would be like asking *how many times in a row a coin comes up tails before it comes up heads*?  With smaller values of *p*, we would expect many failures before we get a success.

The implementation being tested is essentially:  `while (!(rand.NextDouble() < p)) count++;`

Here is a plot of the histogram of outcomes for *count*.

[image]

Immediately obvious is the irregularity at x=54.  For some reason, it is approximately **half as likely as it should** be for a series of exactly 54 random numbers greater than or equal to *p* to be generated in a row.

The actual *p* I'm checking in this test is 1/32.  (Doesn't really matter, as long as it's small enough to get some measurable number of 54's as an outcome.) And I'm counting 10000000 total successes.  (Also doesn't seem to matter.)  It also doesn't matter what random seed I use.

Obviously this is a quirk of the pseudo-random number generator being used by the `Random.NextDouble` function in .NET.  But I'd like to know **why** does this otherwise uniform data have such a striking single spike in such an oddly specific and consistent place?  What is it about this particular pseudo-random number generator that makes generating exactly 54 large numbers in a row followed by a small number half as likely as any other sequence length?

I would have expected many more non-uniform anomalies as it degenerates, not just this one spike.

---

Here is the code that generated this data set:

```cs
using System;

namespace RandomTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random rand = new Random(1);
            int numTrials = 10000000;
            int[] hist = new int[512];
            double p = 1.0 / 32.0;
            for (int i = 0; i < numTrials; ++i) {
                int count = 0;
                while (!(rand.NextDouble() < p)) {
                    count++;
                }
                if (count > hist.Length - 1) {
                    count = hist.Length - 1;
                }
                hist[count]++;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < hist.Length; ++i) {
                Console.WriteLine("{0},{1}", i, hist[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In case it's relevant, this is .Net Framework 4.7.2 on Windows x86.

Comment: Weird that it is 54, there's a magical `56` in it: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/random.cs#L105

Comment: Aha, i think this one: https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/random.cs#L66

Comment: @ericlippert had a very long series on his blog about improving `Random`. He might address this in one of the early posts.

Comment: Personally, I think this question is more suited to https://math.stackexchange.com (or similar) as its about the statistical probability of the distribution algorithm

Comment: @TheGeneral not really, if you look at source code for `System.Random` (links I provided above), 54 is indeed a magical number in reference to `Knuth` although they don't cite any of his works here so I don't have enough context to say what exactly they are talking about there

Comment: @zaitsman My point is, its easy to pick out that there is *seemingly* a correlation, but the OP is asking why? This is not a bug per-se, but a feature/fault/shortcomming of the algorithm, and although this is a programming question (nothing wrong with it, i find it interesting myself), i think the kids over at stats or math would be in a better position to answer the statistical nature of the problem (potentially)

Comment: I think @zaitsman got the right line... the point is: your test does not test the random distribution in general. Instead it tests the following: **if my last random result was a large number**, how many randoms does it take to get the next large number? And since a random number is stored in the seed array and this exact array position is re-used 54 randoms later (seed array is a ring buffer with index 1-55 iterated in sequence), it can be explained why a random value affects the result of 54 values later in some way.

Comment: More thoughts: I just checked the values that are produced when a small number occurs at count 54: it averages to ~0,021, which indicates that the value is not evenly distributed between 0 and 0,031 (p)

Comment: And ofcourse I confused "large number" with "small number" in my first comment...

Comment: Just confirmed with .NET Core 3.1.

Comment: And .NET Core 5.0 Preview 7 has the same problem

Comment: @Wyck, you might want to file bug report for 5.0, it is in preview and might get a fix

Comment: I doubt that anybody would bother "improving" random number generator in the standard library. There is just too much unknown stuff that may inadvertently rely on some quirks of the random number generator. Nobody would want to deal with a ton of potential weird bugs just to make some graph look good.

Comment: It is interesting. It is fun. It is not a problem.

Comment: @Wyck, I've raised the issue with .NET Core 5 Preview7, it might be fixed before release, for anything older I would venture you're out of luck

Comment: MS acknowledged the problem and referred me to [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/23198)

Comment: For Random() without seed this seems to have been fixed. See the source: https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Random.cs

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code on framework 4.8 and I got point 28 to be the outlier:

[image: plot of generated data]

Then, I ran it again without any changes, and 58 was the outlier:

[image: 2nd plot of data]

My Guess as to the cause of the issue you perceive is that the random generator is random.

Running the code yields different results each time, and it appears to be random where the outlier is.

Since, we know that the outlier is random, we can conclude that it is not a fault in a specific line of code. Because of this we can assume that the random outlier could be caused by mere chance that the generator picked a number significantly less than others. The randomness of randomness.